# Display php result after html

Tags: php, html, forms, pdo

I have a `form` where people can search the database for a certain user. When they search for the user and click submit, they're re-directed to a different page and the results are displayed.

My only issue is that the results are being displayed before the required html tags - here's an example of what the page looks like through Inspect Element:

```
"Bobby123


"
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I display the results AFTER the required html tags? How do I set a "set place" for the results to be displayed?

Here's my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $term = $_POST['search'];
    $searchuser = $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE :term");
    $stmt->bindValue(':term', '%'.$term.'%');
    $stmt->execute();
    if($searchuser->rowCount() > 0) {
        while($row = $searchuser->fetch()){
            $name = $row['username'];
            echo $name;
        }
    }else{
        echo 'No results';
    }
}
?>

<form method="post" action="results.php">
<input name="search" type="search">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

The code on results.php simply is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
</html>
```

**If possible, I would not like to use coding like Javascript, Jquery, or anything that is run on the client side.**

Comment: how are you displaying the result in results.php without any php code?

Comment: Don't echo, store the results and put them where the belong in the document.

Comment: @raptor96 The `action` tag in the `form` element displays the results in results.php

Comment: @chris85 How would I do that?

Comment: You really should discover templates..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
if($searchuser->rowCount() > 0) {
    while($row = $searchuser->fetch()){
    $name = $row['username'];
    echo $name;
}}else{
    echo 'No results';
}
}
```

use

```
if($searchuser->rowCount() > 0) {
    $content = "";
    while($row = $searchuser->fetch()){
        $content .= '<p>' . $row['username'] . '</p>';
    }
}else{
    $content = 'No results';
}
```

Then, in your HTML (where you want the text to display)

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<?PHP echo $content; ?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Just tried that code out, and it does display the result in the requested place, however it only displays one result from the database.

Comment: @carve23.himd you need to store it to an array then iterate through the array in your HTML.

Comment: Thanks @carve23.himd. I should add that if you have multiple names, you'll first want to set $content = ""; outside of the while loop,  then put $content .= $name; inside the while loop so that you display multiple names.

Comment: @fislerdata That code was in a loop, so try `$content .= $name;` It wont look right but it will at least show all the data

Comment: Could simplify assignment to `$content .= $row['username'];`.

Comment: Hope you dont mind a small edit, just to make things look a little better in the resulting page